# For looping through a JSON formatted string versus JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a valid JSON string stored in a cassandra column that is about 1MB but could grow to (worst case) 50MB and it could be retrieved by over a 1000 people at anyone time.
When the string is retrieved JSON.parse is called to convert the string to a JSON object before doing any operation in node

most of the time, the operation is to pull out a single key:value.

It seems inefficient to have to convert a the "whole" string to the object first, only to pull out a single key:value, so i thought it would be better to just for-loop through the string, till i find the required key.

This however presents its challenges e,g nested objects, escaped characters etc

> 1) is there a simple JSON string parser that can iterate through a
>   JSON string?
>
> 2) an alternative is to store the JSON object in
>   memcache, it does mean duplicate data (cassandra and memcache) but in
>   different formats (string and object respectively), is this more
>   efficient or a bit much?
>
> 3) I saw [clarinet](http://writings.nunojob.com/2011/12/clarinet-sax-based-evented-streaming-json-parser-in-javascript-for-the-browser-and-nodejs.html), but the authors tests
>   shows that JSON.parse still out performed clarinet on a big file
>
> 4) any other ideas?

Comment: Does the object need to be that big? Maybe some of the data could be stored in related records so it's not so heavy to load it into memory.

Comment: the data grows as user adds more messages, so potenially after a period of time it could be that big, unless as you mentioned, i could split he data into "string chunks" and store them in multiple cassandra columns...this could work, i have to decide what the size of a "chunk" will be and a search operation will need to load each chunk into memory till it finds the required key:value ...this is do-able i guess

Comment: The reason that JSON.parse is faster is probably because it has a native implementation. I expect that as the size of the object increases a SAX style parser will start to gain ground. But you'd have to benchmark the two to see which is faster in your case. But caching or doing what @JimmyCuadra said is probably a better choice.